# Received unexpected end-of-file in filezilla

Tags: vpn, sftp

I am facing one issue with FileZilla in window OS. I don't know other client.
Problem is that.I have search already but there are no correct answer.

One more thing. First I am using vpn connection in Windows 10 then connect sftp. It was working for me since 3 month ago. But I did update FileZilla then it is not working.

[image: Received unexpected end-of-file]

Comment: what error can you see in the log on server? Does it work if you downgrade the FileZilla (I guess not, it looks like server issue)/

Comment: Yes it is working downgrade filezilla. Also my client say it is working on mac.

Comment: please, post the whole log from failed and not-failed login, ideally more verbose (Edit -> Settings -> Debug). And not as an image.